# get-childitem sort-object : how to sort by CreationDate

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to get the functionality of cmd.exe's "dir /o:d" in PowerShell.
I have tried:

```
(gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationDate)    

d----         1/15/2013  11:46 AM   
d----          3/5/2013   4:54 PM  
d----         1/15/2013  12:31 PM  
d----         5/10/2013  10:08 AM  
d----         5/17/2013   2:21 PM  
d----         5/15/2013  10:09 AM  
d----         5/15/2013   6:00 PM  
d----         4/15/2013   8:10 AM
```

Similarly,

```
(gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime)      

d----         1/15/2013  11:46 AM    
d----         1/15/2013  12:31 PM   
d----          3/5/2013   4:54 PM  
d----         5/15/2013   6:00 PM      
d----         5/15/2013  10:09 AM     
d----         5/10/2013  10:08 AM     
d----         5/17/2013   2:21 PM   
d----         4/15/2013   8:10 AM
```

What am I missing to make the directory list sort by creation date?
TIA for any insights...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works for me:

```
gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select name,creationtime
```

Your output show `LastWriteTime` and not `CreationTime`.

And '`CreationDate`' not exists as property for a `file/Directory object`.

Comment: Thanks.  I was overlooking that I had to specifically select CreationTime to be displayed.

Answer (score 17):

`dir /od` sorts by modification time. If you want to do the same thing in powershell, you need to sort by the last write time, and not by creation time.

So that would be :

```
gci | sort lastwritetime
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the command below to get the files sorted by date:

```
gci | sort creationtime
```